# top -bn1 not giving correct CPU usage

Tags: cpu, top, cpu-usage

I am logging on to a node which I know has near 100% cpu usage (20 single process jobs using nearly 100% cpu each). When I use `top` interactively, the first iteration, it gives me about 20% `ni` and the next iteration and all after it correctly gives 95+% `ni` usage. I am wanting to pipe the output of `top` via `top -bn1 > outfile`, but the first iteration of `top -bn1` (the only iteration) gives the incorrect CPU usage. If I use `top -bn2`, then the second iteration gives the correct usage, but that is too much output.

How can I get `top -bn1` to correctly give me the CPU usage? I am writing this script for usage statistics, so if necessary, I can go back and run an analysis on the processes independently to generate my own CPU usage, but it would be nice if `top` would give me the correct usage right off the bat.

EDIT: `mpdstat -P ALL` gives me the same, incorrect, initial usage statistics. It would be nice to get that figured out as well too. I can use `mpstat -P ALL 1 1`, but this gives the output twice.

Comment: `ni` refers to the CPU usage influenced by process "niceness." Just issuing the `top` command with default priority will interfere with that number. (I'm assuming here that these "20 single process jobs using nearly 100% cpu [sic] each" have a non-zero nice value.)

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that I am causing the 100% `ni` value by invoking top. However, when I top on an idle node, I get `0.0%ni` as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to say just the opposite. The 20% `ni` value is due to invoking `top`, which is using more "not nice" CPU (which would be reported in the `us` category, more than likely). The first invocation causes the drop because of invoking `top`. That's why the **second** value appears more correct.

Comment: So you are saying that the `ni` value is dropped AT FIRST due to me invoking `top` and then it goes back to normal on the second iteration? Why would it change at all since `top -bn2` is just invoking two iterations of `top`?

Comment: The second "iteration" doesn't include starting up `top` itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just drop the output of the first iteration.

```
top -bn2 | awk '/^top -/ { p=!p } { if (!p) print }'
```

Comment: So what's wrong with -bn1? I have the feeling -bn1 shows longer time average, as I found it changes slower. Not sure if this is the case?

Comment: The first iteration includes the start up of  `top` itself and is therefore inaccurate.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen: see [this comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619#c3).

Answer (score 0):

There are tools which first display an calculated average. Other tools have an incomplete first sample. Overall it is advised to skip the first sample to get the desired result.